# Is it possible to create Literal replacements for general code, not just custom snippets?

Tags: c#, templates

I'm looking to create a database application that will serve as a template for a series of similar apps, but I'd like to know if there's a way of creating replaceable literals (such as method names) within my code so that when I create a new app using the template and can easily identify which literals I need to change from the generic sounding literal created from the template.

Basically, is there a similar method to how custom code snippets can be created with replaceable literals using xml tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into Microsoft [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

This is a standard .NET infrastructure and a set of tools to generate code from data.

Answer (score 2):

I think what what you are looking for is tangible. You could something like this to edit and create your templates:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tangibleengineeringGmbH.tangibleT4Editor230plusmodelingtoolsforVS2015